# Allow the use of camera phones in the manufacturing facilities; but then how do I maintain the security of the premises

Tags: mobile, physical

What are the best practices to be followed to maintain security in the manufacturing site where camera phones are allowed?

I'm working on one of the largest manufacturing facility where few of the R&D/IT/HR team sits in the same shop floor but in one of the designated areas. Though we have restricted the usage of camera phones for the people working in assembly line so that they would be not able to take pics of the OT/IoT CIS systems, The other set of people working on R&D/IT/HR are allowed to carry the phones. This poses the security risk as to they could capture the pictures of the shop floor.

We could not ask the employees not to use phones as it will block the access to business tools. One use case is use of google authenticator and SMS for MFA and increased security. Issuing duck phones(basic phones) is not a solution as we would not be able to use Google authenticator and any other office tools.

Additionally, as we are used to mobile/smart phones in this era, people from all age groups, designations (developer <-> CXO's) would not accept if I block the use of phones using physical security(metal detector) check.

We have added a physical security control of camera-block tamper evident stickers. However, this is a failure as everybody uses mobile case/cover and the sticker is eventually pasted on the cover covering camera lens. This leads people to remove the phone from the cover and take snaps.

So my question is that, how do we maintain security such that no photos are taken in the site?.

Comment: Why do you think that the problem are camera phones in the first place? If somebody really wants to spy - cameras are so tiny today that they can be easily hidden and pictures can be taken without anybody noticing. So camera phones are  not actually needed, they might even be too obvious for spying.

Comment: Physical security including metal detectors will address these problems to an extent. But a mobile phone which is a whitelisted good to carry should not be restricted to film/snap the shop floor. However, I do agree that if the if a person's intent is to spy, he will discover one or the other mechanism. But chances are less as he would get caught when physical checks happen!.

Comment: The only controls I can think of would be administrative controls, putting in place policies and rules that reduce the risk of workers taking pictures in areas counter to policy. Signage, training.